# Objective C - Difference between Implementation and Extending

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Just a general question regarding the difference between extending a class and implementing it.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

In my example my class AppDelegate extends from the UIResponder Class but implements the UIApplicationDelegate class.

Can somebody please explain... Do you have also possibilities to access methods of the UIApplicationDelegate object/ class? Where are the differences?

Thanks

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate is not a class but a protocol.

Comment: ok... a protocol... so you can just implement protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are speaking in Java terms, then in your example you are Extending (generally referred to as Subclassing) the UIResponder class.

Your example is also implementing the UIApplicationDelegate which is similar to implementing an Interface where you have to define the required methods of the UIApplicationDelegate Protocol and you have the option of implementing the optional methods.

Similar to Java, you can only extend or subclass one class but you can implement multiple delegate protocols in your class

Apple's guide to Protocols is very handy if you want to understand more: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Comment: ahh .. ok got it... so implementing means just to bind an architectural structure plan of methods and other elements to a class. .. right?

Answer (score 0):

At very basic level we can see this a form to achieve multiple inheritence in objective C.

As only single inheritence is supported by objective C, but we can achieve multiple iinheritence by using protocols(Which is similar to interfaces in java).

So When we subclass a class - then we say we extend that.

and when we use protocol to access common functionality(in order to have multiple inheritende) - we say it implements.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a class = subclassing it. I.e. the methods you don't override will be called in the superclass.

Implementing a delegate protocol simply says what methods your class is supposed to have implemented.

See (for example) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1

and

http://www.thepensiveprogrammer.com/2010/05/objective-c-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: ... ok implementing means to assign an interface of rules to my class... right?

Comment: I guess you could put it that way, yes. In java-speak, you would be "implementing an interface".

Comment: Thats the direction I come from ;)